# Voting Stats For Money.SE

Tags: discussion, voting, stats

On the Math site I saw this post in the Meta section -

[Up and Down Vote Statistics](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11992/up-and-downvote-statistics?cb=1)

Can a Mod respond with data for Money.SE? Curious how our stats look in comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here is a chart that I hope satisfies your curiosity. SE Mod said I could post this one.

*(Beta sites shouldn't obsess over data like this.  When we graduate, our info gets moved into http://data.stackexchange.com/ and the stataholic among us can go bonkers.  It really shouldn't be too much longer now.)*

As I see it, the downvotes are such a small percent of our activity, they rarely spike.  They are probably drowned out by the US tax time up-votes

[image: Voting Chart for the past year on money.stackexchange.com]

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. It looks good.

Comment: Speaking of good numbers, we're *this* >< close to exceeding 10,000 visitors/day.  I've been watching that statistic on our home page for a long time waiting for us to break through. Of course, the holidays are coming up, and that's usually a slow period. Picks up again in the new year and tax time is busy (as above!)

Comment: Coincidentally, we just hit it!  Today's stat: **"10,241 visitors/day"** !

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea - coincidence, or DESTINY!?!?

Comment: And still no full graduation :) ... the guys at stackexchange are still doing/finalizing the designs :)